# Conditionally scale values in a crosstable according to a category in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have a cross table where the rows are different companies. I'd like to scale one row in this crosstable by some factor. For example, say I have a column named "Company" containing strings like "FORD", "GMC", etc. In my crosstable, I'd like to multiply the "GMC" row by 0.7. How would I do that? (Besides creating a new calculated column.)

Comment: Have you checked expessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "Cell values" you'll want to enter a custom expression. Something like the follow should do the trick:

```
If(First([Company]) = "GMC", sum([value]) * .7, sum([value]))
```

For multiple conditionals, use a `case` statement rather than `if`. The custom expression will demand any columns coming in have an aggregation method associated to them. Replace `sum` and `value` with whatever numerical information it is you are trying to display (i.e. `sum([cashflow])`, `count([Company])`).